# Test Class for my Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am completely lost at writing a test class for this trigger to give it code coverage. It's a trigger that does a checkbox on a custom object `Involvement__c` after a `File` has been uploaded. That checkbox then initiates a workflow.

I've attempted to write a test class, but I really don't know what I'm doing. I'm not savvy enough to know how to write a correct test class, I copied this code from here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AevbIAC

I've updated the necessary parts to work with Files. This works in my sandbox, but I just need a test class to get me the rest of the way. Help!

```
trigger InvFileTrigger on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {

Set<Id> objectIds = new Set<Id>();

for(ContentDocumentLink a:trigger.new){
    String keyPrefix = String.valueOf(a.LinkedEntityId).substring(0,3);

    if(keyPrefix == 'a1d'){
        objectIds.add(a.LinkedEntityId);
    }
}


if(objectIds.size() > 0){
    List<Involvement__c> InvolvementList = [SELECT Id FROM Involvement__c WHERE Id IN :objectIds];

    for(Involvement__c obj:InvolvementList){
        obj.Send_Attachment_Email__c = true;
    }

    if(InvolvementList.size() > 0){
        update InvolvementList;
    }       
}

}
```

Comment: What You have tried so far

Comment: Hi DCole. We have a lot of good resources we tend to recommend to help you learn unit testing, including [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests), Trailhead's [module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing) on unit tests, and the Salesforce Developer Blog's [Month of Testing](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/month-of-testing-apex-testing-in-depth-part-2-of-3.html) series. There are also hundreds of questions you can review here. SFSE doesn't write unit tests for you, but you can ask when you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly Read this below trailhead after that you will able to write the test class.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro

For this Trigger, you need to create dummy data for contentdocument object,ContentDocumentLink object and Involvement__c object.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot and report back if I have issues.